# In a normal image classification using cnn's? what should be the value of the units in the dense layer?

Tags: image, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am just creating a normal image classifier for rock-paper-scissors.I am using my local gpu itself and it isnt a high end gpu. When i began training the model it kept giving the error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape.
```

I googled this error and they suggested I decrease my batch size which i did. It still did not solve anything however later I changed my image size to 50*50 initially it was 200*200 and then it started training with an accuracy of 99%. 
Later i wanted to see if i could do it with 150*150 sized images as i found a tutorial on the official tensorflow channel on youtube I followed their exact code and it still did not work. I reduced the batch size, still no solution. Later I changed the no. of units in the dense layer initially it was 512 and then i decreased it to 200 and it worked fine but now the accuracy is pretty trash. I was just wondering is there anyway I could tune my model according to my gpu without affecting my accuracy? So I was just wondering how does the no. of units in the dense layer matter? It would really  help me alot.

```
    i=Input(shape=X_train[0].shape)
    x=Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu')(i)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x=Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x=MaxPool2D((2,2))(x)
    x=Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x=Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu')(x)
    x=BatchNormalization()(x)
    x=MaxPool2D((2,2))(x)
    x=Flatten()(x)
    x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x=Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)
    x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x=Dense(3,activation='softmax')(x)
    model=Model(i,x)
```

okay now when I run this with image size of 150*150 it throws that error,
if I change the size of the image to 50*50 and reduce batch size to 8 it works and gives me an accuracy of 99. but if I use 150*150 and reduce the no. of units in the dense layer to 200(random) it works fine but accuracy is very very bad.
I am using a low end nvidia geforce mx 230 gpu.
And my vram is 4 gigs

Comment: Please post the model you use, what batch size you use now and how much VRAM you have.

Comment: Hey I have updated my statement please check. Thanks!!!

Comment: What kind of batch size are you using with 200x200 and 150x150 images? And what do you mean by very very bad accuracy, how long are you training?

Comment: both 150 and 200 throw that error. I changed the size of the image to 50 and then run it. it gives a good accuracy. For both 150/200 and 50 i used a batch size of 8. Bad accuracy as in it trains and shows an accuracy of 95 but the accuracy score is like 34 and validation loss is like around 4. I trained it for 50 epochs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 200x200 images the output of the last MaxPool has a shape of (50,50,128) which is then flattened and serves as the input of the Dense layer giving you in total of 50*50*128*512=163840000 parameters. This is a lot.

To reduce the amount of parameters you can do one of the following:
- reduce the amount of filters in the last Conv2D layer
- do a MaxPool of more than 2x2
- reduce the size of the Dense layer
- reduce the size of the input images.

You have already tried the two latter options. You will only find out by trial and error which method ultimately gives you the best accuracy. You were already at 99%, which is good.

If you want a platform with more VRAM available, you can use Google Colab https://colab.research.google.com/

Comment: This was the Training accuracy and my accuracy score was almost the same , But this was when I reduced the image size to 50*50. Alright so basically if i have to use the same size image I gotta find ways to decrease the parameters by using the options you suggested!!!! Alright thanks alot !!!! Really helped me alot!! Are there any other resources where i can learn up on this!!

Comment: If this answer was sufficent, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Keras has a lot of examples.
Here is image classification on 10x10 images for CIFAR dataset:
https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/

Another good one from Keras blog:

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html